# WebBrowser Control; Set Page Height?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, winforms

Is there any way to forcefully set the `Document` height (ie page height) using either C# to access the control, or javascript to modify the page's values?

I'm injecting text via a script and the `Document` height/width doesn't update no mater how many entries are added to the page.

Comment: Why you do need to control document height? It should extend automatically as content is added. There's probably something wrong with your CSS otherwise.

Comment: Because the content is inserted via `element.appendChild()` inside the actual HTML document. In updating/adding content this way, the document's external height is never updated in the control.  I add content until it exceeds the height of the window, appending to the bottom each time. The window automatically sets the bottom visible but I can see partial text extending above the height of the window.. However no scrollbars are ever shown and the mousewheel does not allow scrolling. Not even click+drag scrolling works. It's DOM content and not updating the actual page height.